# React Native Module, Cocoapod file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, react-native-native-module

I am building a module for React Native, as a part of this, there is some native iOS code that is wrapped in a cocoapod. I have this working fine, and I can install the cocoapod and see the native classes from the RN side no problem. One of the native classes is trying to get the path to a local mp3 file inside a sub folder `proj/Audio/file.mp3`. Using the following ObjC code: `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Audio"];`

This is returning `nil` and as such causing an error when trying to get the `NSURL` for the file. I have the mp3 extension added to the `podspec` @ `s.source_files = "ios/**/*.{h,m,swift,mp3}"` so it is moving the file over. However, I assume I have to be missing something as it ultimately cannot find the file.

I have gone into the source xcode project and added the `mp3` file to the `Copy files` phase in build phases. I have also made sure that the file was linked to the target. I am not sure what else I could be missing at this point for it to not be able to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the mp3 file in `source_files` of your podspec, try using `resource_bundles`; see the documentation [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles). Basically it lets you define resource bundle files that CocoaPods creates for you with the assets that you specify, for example:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
'Audio' => ['ios/**/*.mp3']
}
```

You can load the bundle file resource that CocoaPods created (create a `NSBundle` object from its URL by its name - `Audio` in the above example, and extension - `bundle`), then get a path from resources inside this bundle (the same method that you used on the `mainBundle`).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was struggling with this myself. I completely agree with [Artal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4185269/artal), to sum up you need to

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Audio", ofType: "bundle");
let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath!)
```

maybe guard your the path,